How can I fix Error in Flutter Flow Local Notifications Code?
I am working on a schedule local notification for a  healthcare application and while I am trying to build the apk I'm facing the following error
Error Message
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
/opt/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_local_notifications-15.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/dexterous/flutterlocalnotifications/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:1019: error: reference to bigLargeIcon is ambiguous
bigPictureStyle.bigLargeIcon(null);
^
both method bigLargeIcon(Bitmap) in BigPictureStyle and method bigLargeIcon(Icon) in BigPictureStyle match
1 error
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_local_notifications:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.


Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 9s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
requestNotificationPermission

// Automatic FlutterFlow imports
import '/backend/backend.dart';
import '/backend/schema/structs/index.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_util.dart';
import '/custom_code/actions/index.dart'; // Imports other custom actions
import '/flutter_flow/custom_functions.dart'; // Imports custom functions
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// Begin custom action code
// DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THE CODE ABOVE!

import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:timezone/data/latest.dart' as tzdata;
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;

Future<void> scheduleNotification(
  String title,
  String content,
  String time, // Change the type to String for the time parameter
) async {
  // Print the provided time for debugging
  print('Provided time: $time');

  await requestNotificationPermissions();
  // Parse the time string into a DateTime object
  DateTime parsedTime = DateFormat.jm().parse(time);

  // Initialize the timezone database
  tzdata.initializeTimeZones();

  // Schedule notification based on the provided time
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  // Initialize the Android-specific settings for the notification
  var androidSettings = AndroidNotificationDetails(
    'channel_id',
    'channel_name',
    importance: Importance.high,
    priority: Priority.high,
    icon:
        '@mipmap/ic_launcher', // Replace with your small icon name without the extension
  );

  // Initialize the notification details
  var notificationDetails =
      NotificationDetails(android: androidSettings, iOS: null);

  // Get the device's timezone
  var deviceTimeZone = tz.local;

  // Convert the provided time to the device's timezone
  var scheduledTime = tz.TZDateTime.from(parsedTime, deviceTimeZone);

  // Schedule the notification
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
    0,
    title!,
    content!,
    scheduledTime,
    notificationDetails,
    androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
    uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
        UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
    matchDateTimeComponents: DateTimeComponents.time,
    payload: 'Custom_Sound',
  );
}

// Set your action name, define your arguments and return parameter,
// and then add the boilerplate code using the green button on the right!




scheduleNotification

// Automatic FlutterFlow imports
import '/backend/backend.dart';
import '/backend/schema/structs/index.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_util.dart';
import '/custom_code/actions/index.dart'; // Imports other custom actions
import '/flutter_flow/custom_functions.dart'; // Imports custom functions
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// Begin custom action code
// DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THE CODE ABOVE!

import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:timezone/data/latest.dart' as tzdata;
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;

Future<void> scheduleNotification(
  String title,
  String content,
  String time, // Change the type to String for the time parameter
) async {
  // Print the provided time for debugging
  print('Provided time: $time');

  await requestNotificationPermissions();
  // Parse the time string into a DateTime object
  DateTime parsedTime = DateFormat.jm().parse(time);

  // Initialize the timezone database
  tzdata.initializeTimeZones();

  // Schedule notification based on the provided time
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  // Initialize the Android-specific settings for the notification
  var androidSettings = AndroidNotificationDetails(
    'channel_id',
    'channel_name',
    importance: Importance.high,
    priority: Priority.high,
    icon:
        '@mipmap/ic_launcher', // Replace with your small icon name without the extension
  );

  // Initialize the notification details
  var notificationDetails =
      NotificationDetails(android: androidSettings, iOS: null);

  // Get the device's timezone
  var deviceTimeZone = tz.local;

  // Convert the provided time to the device's timezone
  var scheduledTime = tz.TZDateTime.from(parsedTime, deviceTimeZone);

  // Schedule the notification
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
    0,
    title!,
    content!,
    scheduledTime,
    notificationDetails,
    androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
    uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
        UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
    matchDateTimeComponents: DateTimeComponents.time,
    payload: 'Custom_Sound',
  );
}

// Set your action name, define your arguments and return parameter,
// and then add the boilerplate code using the green button on the right!

My Flutterflow app version is 5.0
pubspec dependencies
timezone: ^0.9.2
flutter_local_notifications:^15.1.1
I tried creating a notification system for my healthcare application we are getting the mentioned error while building the apk

Check your flutter java version.
